# AdjacencyMatrix: Unexpected output

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph defined as follow:

```
r = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

then I want to get the adjacency matrix of this graph by using the `AdjacencyMatrix` function. I doubt the output is incorrect, at least, it is not as I expected

`AdjacencyMatrix[r]`

[image: Adjacency Matrix]

Take the first row as example, if it corresponds to vertex `1`, this row should be

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Does anyone could help me to explain this output?

Comment: it is correct. The node numbering in the matrix are actually listed as `VertexList[r]` , which is `{1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node numbering in the matrix are actually listed as `VertexList[r]` , which is `{1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7}` I am not sure why Mathematica does it this way, it does not seem natural to me.

```
r = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7}, 
          VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To reorder the matrix:

```
m = AdjacencyMatrix[r];
z = VertexList[r];
m0 = m[[z, z]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Probably it does this because you can put as vertices anything you want, also things like images etc. Reordering in such cases would be problematic.

Comment: It's a so nice explanation. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @fetag: If it fully answers your question, feel free to mark it as such by clicking the accepted answer checkmark below the answer score tag.